# How would I test sending a route with mocha/chai/superagent in express?

Tags: node.js, testing, express, mocha.js, chai

```
    it('sends login page if we\'re logged out at /', function (done) {
            superagent.get('http://localhost:4000/').end(function(err, res){
                if(err) {return done(err)}
                expect(res).to.have.property('status', 200);


                //how would i do something like this? 
                expect(res.viewRendered).to.be.equal('index.ejs')
                done();
            });
        });
```

I'm new to testing and I hate it.. a lot. I'm trying to learn the basics and it's the most frustrating learning curve I've ever experienced. I've been looking up documentation for hours and still haven't been able to figure out how to check which route has been rendered

Answer (score 3):

I would go about this another way: instead of relying on the output of the request, and match that up against a template (which can be quite difficult unless you add some sort of identifier to each template, which doesn't feel entirely right), you can take advantage of some internals of Express, and specifically on how it renders templates.

The Express documentation states the following ([here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)):

> Express-compliant template engines such as Pug export a function named `__express(filePath, options, callback)`, which is called by the `res.render()` function to render the template code.

You are not using Pug, but EJS, but the same principle applies: the `ejs` module exports a function called `__express` which will be called with full path of the template that should be rendered. And that also happens to be what you want to test for!

So the question now becomes: *"how can you test that `ejs.__express()` gets called with the proper template name?"*. Answer: you can *spy* on it.

My favorite module for this is [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), so the example below will use that. Sinon is great to spy on existing functions, or to make them do entirely different things if you want.

As an example, I will use the following, very simple, Express app:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', { foo : 'bar' });
});

module.exports = app;
```

We want to test if, when `/` is requested, the template `index.ejs` gets rendered.

Instead of using `superagent`, I'll be using [`supertest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), which is meant for testing HTTP apps.

Here's the annotated Mocha test file:

```
// Import the Express app (from the file above), which we'll be testing.
const app = require('./app');

// Import some other requirements.
const expect    = require('chai').expect;
const supertest = require('supertest');
const sinon     = require('sinon');

// Import the EJS library, because we need it to spy on.  
const ejs = require('ejs');

// Here's the actual test:
it('sends login page if we\'re logged out at /', function (done) {
  // We want to spy on calls made to `ejs.__express`. We use Sinon to
  // wrap that function with some magic, so we can check later on if
  // it got called, and if so, if it got called with the correct
  // template name.
  var spy = sinon.spy(ejs, '__express');

  // Use supertest to retrieve / and make sure that it returns a 200 status
  // (so we don't have to check for that ourselves)
  supertest(app)
    .get('/')
    .expect(200)
    .end((err, res) => {
      // Pass any errors to Mocha.
      if (err) return done(err);

      // Magic! See text below.
      expect(spy.calledWithMatch(/\/index\.ejs$/)).to.be.true;

      // Let Sinon restore the original `ejs.__express()` to its original state.
      spy.restore();

      // Tell Mocha that our test case is done.
      done();
    });
});
```

So what's this magic:

```
spy.calledWithMatch(/\/index\.ejs$/)
```

It means: *"return `true` if the function that was being spied on (`ejs.__express()`) got called with a first argument that matches the regular expression `\/index\.ejs$`"*. Which is what you want to test for.

The reason I'm using a regular expression here is because I'm lazy. Because the first argument (`filePath` in the quote above) will contain the *full* path to the template file, it can be quite long. You can directly test for it if you want:

```
spy.calledWith(__dirname + '/views/index.ejs')
```

But that would break if the location of the template directory got changed. So, like I said, I'm lazy, and I'll use a regular expression match instead.

With tools like `supertest`, `sinon` and `chai`, testing can actually become fun (honest!). I have to agree that the learning curve is rather steep, but perhaps that an annotated example like this can help you get a better idea on what's possible and how to go about it.

Comment: Uncaught AssertionError: expected false to be true

this is why I hate testing.. now I have no idea how to fix this problem and no idea where to even look. it's making such an easy part of a program turn into a multi hour frustrating problem solve

Comment: Start with the basics: is your route actually getting called at all? Don't worry with setting up a test case for it at first, just call `console.log()` right before your route calls `res.render()`.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely being called. I'm actually trying to redo a website I've made with a TDD approach and figuring out how to test everything is very difficult, it feels like I'm doing tenfold extra work

Comment: If it gets called, you can try this in your test case, before the `expect(...).to.be.true`: `console.log(spy.getCall(0).args)`. That would log all the arguments with which `ejs.__express()` got called. Or assert that `spy.called` is true; if not, the spy may be faulty (although it works in my example).

Comment: { settings:
     { 'x-powered-by': true,
       etag: 'weak',
       'etag fn': [Function: wetag],
       env: 'development',
       'query parser': 'extended',
       'query parser fn': [Function: parseExtendedQueryString],
       'subdomain offset': 2,
       'trust proxy': false,
       'trust proxy fn': [Function: trustNone],
       view: [Function: View],
       views: 'C:\\Users\\J\\WebstormProjects\\project\\views',
       'jsonp callback name': 'callback',
       'view engine': 'ejs' },
    _locals: {},
    cache: false },
  [Function] ]